# Javascript setTimeout() issues involving brackets

Tags: javascript, loops, timeout, sleep

This is my first javascript program and I'm just attempting to disaply a string of varying length in a webpage. I have a few issues currently. The main one causing me problems is the setTimeout having issues with a function inside it. I get an error saying there is no bracket after arguement list.

```
function main() {
    n = true
    name = ""
    if (n = true) {
        name = display(name)
        document.getElementById("triangle").innerHTML = name
        setTimeout(funtion() { console.log(slept) }, 100)
    } else {
        main()
    }
}
```

Also is there a cleaner way to loop infinitely (or near infinitely) and display to a website. This was causing some errors before I further broke it playing with other things.

Comment: what is slept? a variable?

Comment: @Addis its just a simple phrase to show it worked. Past tense of sleep. I would have noticed it wasnt a string but it wasn't giving that error so it didn't really matter at the time

Comment: great! I hope you have got your answer now, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misspelled function, it should be

```
setTimeout(function() { console.log(slept) }, 100)
```